# Modifying Line Thickness in PdfSharp vb.net

Tags: vb.net, pdfsharp

I am writing a program in vb.net using the PdfSharp dll library to generate a pdf based upon user-entered values.

I am trying to adjust the look & feel of the pdf and one thing I noticed is that PdfSharp does not seem to offer a way of adjusting line thickness. This is especially frustrating since the default line thickness is quite heavy and looks overly bold. 
[Example of Default Line Thickness](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djWhI.gif)

Here is the code I am currently using. Does anyone know of a way to fix the line thickness?

```
        'Outter Left Line
        gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, 290, 85, 290, 145)
        'Outter Right Line
        gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, 530, 85, 530, 145)
        'Line Dividing Fields
        gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, 388, 85, 388, 145)

        'Rows 1-2 Outline
        gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, 290, 85, 530, 85)
        gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, 290, 97, 530, 97)
        'Rows 2-3 Outline
        gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, 290, 109, 530, 109)
        gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, 290, 121, 530, 121)
        'Rows 3-4 Outline
        gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, 290, 133, 530, 133)
        gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, 290, 145, 530, 145)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the pen.

```
Dim myColorPen As New XPen(XColors.Black, 2)
g.DrawLine(myColorPen, New XPoint, New XPoint)
```

Comment: Is that thickness parameter in milimeter?